# Met SettingWithCopyWarning when trying adding a new column with constant in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

As described in title, why this warning becomes so sensitive today?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtaHZ.png)

I dont know whats the state-of-the-art way to create a new column filled with constant? Tried all old ways, and all got this warning.

I prefer not to use .copy() function coz it is a pretty large table.